# eraseFromParent() Error

Tags: c++, llvm, llvm-ir

I'm trying to delete some instructions in IR. For analysis purpose, these instructions are inserted before, and now I need to delete them.

```
  BasicBlock::reverse_iterator I = (*b).rbegin();
  BasicBlock::reverse_iterator Ie = (*b).rend();
  int i=0;
  for ( ; I != Ie;I++)
    {
     if(i>0&&i<4){
       errs()<<" Instruction "<<*I<<"\n";
       I->eraseFromParent();
       i++;
    }
     else{
       i++;
     }
   }
```

This code is used in Transformation pass. When I run it, the output error are:

```
       #0 0x00000000032bff15 (opt+0x32bff15)
       #1 0x00000000032bffa6 (opt+0x32bffa6)
       #2 0x00000000032be43e (opt+0x32be43e)
       #3 0x00000000032bf8ac (opt+0x32bf8ac)
       #4 0x00007f26cfa81330 __restore_rt (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0+0x10330)
       #5 0x00007f26ce81a89a   llvm::PointerIntPair<llvm::ilist_node_base<true>*, 1u, unsigned int, llvm::PointerLikeTypeTraits<llvm::ilist_node_base<true>*>, llvm::PointerIntPairInfo<llvm::ilist_node_base<true>*, 1u, llvm::PointerLikeTypeTraits<llvm::ilist_node_base<true>*> > >::getInt() const /home/rasha/llvm/llvm/include/llvm/ADT/PointerIntPair.h:59:0
       #6 0x00007f26ce813516 llvm::ilist_node_base<true>::isSentinel() const /home/rasha/llvm/llvm/include/llvm/ADT/ilist_node_base.h:46:0
       #7 0x00007f26ce813536 llvm::ilist_node_base<true>::isKnownSentinel() const /home/rasha/llvm/llvm/include/llvm/ADT/ilist_node_base.h:47:0
       #8 0x00007f 26ce81e1d9 llvm::ilist_iterator<llvm::ilist_detail::node_options<llvm::Instruction, true, false, void>, true, false>::operator*() const /home/rasha/llvm/llvm/include/llvm/ADT/ilist_iterator.h:139:0
       #9 0x00007f26ce812d6f (anonymous namespace)::BBRemove::runOnModule(llvm::Module&) /home/rasha/llvm/llvm/lib/Transforms/BBRemove/BBRemove.cpp:79:0
       #10 0x0000000002c4a2dc (opt+0x2c4a2dc)
       #11 0x0000000002c4aa2c (opt+0x2c4aa2c)
       #12 0x0000000002c4ac6d (opt+0x2c4ac6d)
       #13 0x0000000001512cd4 (opt+0x1512cd4)
       #14 0x00007f26cea6cf45 __libc_start_main /build/eglibc-ripdx6/eglibc-2.19/csu/libc-start.c:321:0
       #15 0x00000000014f7a19 (opt+0x14f7a19)
       Stack dump:
```

This error is issued after the first call of eraseFromParent.

Comment: Don't modify an LLVM list while you're iterating over it. It can work, but it's sailing close to the wind. Demands more brain power than a simple `for(...)` line ought to demand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  BasicBlock::reverse_iterator I = (*b).rbegin();
  BasicBlock::reverse_iterator Ie = (*b).rend();
  stack<Instruction *> workList;
  int i=0;
  for ( ; I != Ie;I++)
    {
     if(i>0&&i<4){
       workList.push_back(I);
       i++;
    }
     else{
       i++;
     }
   }

while(!workList.empty()){
    Instruction *I=workList.pop();
I->eraseFromParent();

}
```

Do not modify instruction within the iterator; collect it first then modify.

Comment: pop function does not have output, I used instead workList.top()->eraseFromParent();
workList.pop();  but it gives me errors Use still stuck around after Def is destroyed

Comment: I could fix the error, I used your idea with std::map<int, Instruction*> int is a counter. Then, I used for loop using iterator wit beginning with wit= workList.begin(), wit->second->eraseFromParent();. Now, it works, thanks a million